# Update sibling components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a collection of products with different options (material, color, size). The selection of an option on the first product have to be mirrored on each of his siblings.

For example, if I select `material: gold` on the first product, all the next are updated depending on this option.

The best idea I came up with was an event system which is shared in higher order components and triggered when the first product changes, but it means that I have to use some refs to call the method `selectOption()` of the siblings...

```
     +------+
     |PARENT|
     |      |
     +------+
     /      \
+-----+    +-----+
| C1  |    | C2  |
|     |    |     |
+-----+    +-----+
   | <-ref    | <-ref
+-----+    +-----+
| P1  |    | P2  |
|     |    |     |
+-----+    +-----+
```

On click on P1 option, I trigger an event in C1, C2 intercepts this event and calls `this.refs.P2.addOption('gold')`

I don't like this solution because it means that I have to flag the product P1 to make it trigger events unlike the others.

Do you have a more elegant idea ?

Comment: [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) explain the preferred way of doing this kind of thing. TL;DR: data should be kept in one place and passed down via props, rather than being duplicated/'synced'. You can pass callbacks as props to allow the child component to send data back to its parents.

Comment: And for what it's worth, in the time I've been using React I've literally *never* had to use refs - they're only really meant to be used if you want to do something outside of the React data flow (the docs refer to it as an 'escape hatch').

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I've already read these articles ant I feel like it doesn't fit my problem well... The thing is I have Options in products, OptionValues in Options and Customizations in OptionValues, and if I try to lift the state up on each of these components and sub-components, it means I have to pass callbacks down a lot of levels and create a super big paren component on top of that... Should I do it anyway ?
Cheers !